# Java Generics - Upper Bounds through layers of inheritance

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, type-bounds

With a single layer of inheritance I can do something like this:

```java
// Dog extends Animal
List<Dog> dogs = ...;

// Cat extends Animal
List<Cat> cats = ...;

List<? extends Animal> animals = new ArrayList<>();
animals.addAll(cats);
animals.addAll(dogs);
```

I can do this without casting, which is nice.

But what if I have a scenario like the following?

```java
// Plant extends LivingBeing
List<Plant> plants = ...;

// Animal extends LivingBeing
// Cat extends Animal
List<Cat> cats = ...;

List<? extends LivingBeing> livingThings = new ArrayList<>();
// This is fine
lvingThings.addAll(plants);

// FIXME: Fails because Cat doesn't directly extend LivingBeing
livingThings.addAll(cats);
```

Is there a way to specify an upper bound that is not a direct parent of all members of the list, so that I can avoid casting?

Comment: Why don't you use a `List<LivingBeing>`?

Comment: As an aside: the current approach violates [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super). The collections `animals` and `livingThings` act as consumer in the code shown.

Comment: The first example doesn't actually work.  In both examples, the correct thing is to remove `? extends`.

Comment: None of the examples that you claim to work, actually work. Did you actually test these code snippets?

Comment: You're probably looking for `? super LivingBeing` instead. See also [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first example doesn't compile. Both are caused by the `? extends` part. The issue is that as soon as the initialization is done, the compiler already forgot the actual type. That means that after initializing `livingThings`, the compiler thinks it can be a `List<LivingBeing>`, `List<Animal>` or `List<Cat>` (all of which would allow adding cats), but also `List<Dog> or` List`, which don't allow cats.

If you want a list with things that can be any type of living being, you must declare it as such: `List<LivingBeing>`. Otherwise you can't add anything anymore except `null`.

The latter is true for any `Collection<? extends T>` for any type `T`. The only value that is safe for any type that matches `? extends T` is `null`.

Comment: In general: `? extends T` allows you to retrieve elements as type `T` without casting, but you can't add anything (except for `null`). `? super T` allows you to add anything that's `T` or a sub type, but you can only retrieve it as `Object`.

Comment: Had a brain lapse for a moment I think. I think for some reason I was assuming I add to a List<? extends T> when mapping differing objects but in reality I just add to a List<superclass> and then access as a List<? extends T>. Thank you!